# ASP.NET Core Web API to connection Oracle 11 g database using ODP ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, oracle11g

I am new in .net core platform then i have no idea to connect oracle db to ASP .net WEB API.

**how to create ASP.NET Core Web API to get the data  from an Oracle database using ODP ORM.?**

It's Code First Approach !!

Comment: Take a look at [Oracle Data Provider for .NET Core Download](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should consider to use NHibernate:

> Hibernate is a mature, open source object-relational mapper for the
>   .NET framework. It's actively developed, fully featured and used in
>   thousands of successful projects. It's built on top of ADO.NET and the
>   current version is NHibernate 4.0.4.

[tutorialpoint NHibernate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_quick_guide.htm)

Answer (score 0):

besides NHibernate you can use Entity Framework Core, this a link to [documentation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx)
The idea is :

1. define your classes(models)
2. define your database context (set configuration and relation between models)
3. saving data